# Need an example of piece wise function continuous but not differentiable

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, exponential-function

I Need an example of piece wise function continuous but not differentiable. One of the functions has to be trigonometric and the other has to be exponential. Please

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=\cos x$ for $x\le 0$ and let $f(x)=e^x$ for $x\gt 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\cos(x)& x\leq 0\\e^x &x>0\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ \sin(|x|) $$
$$ \mathrm{e}^{-|x|} $$

Answer (score 1):

You may consider the function$$f(x)=\sin x$$ for $x<0$ and $$f(x)=e^{2x}-1$$ for $x>0$

Comment: "the functions has to be trigonometric and the other has to be exponential"

Comment: @Dario- Yes, edited accordingly

Comment: This new one is not continuous (moreover it is not defined in 0).

Comment: @Dario- I don't know what is wrong with me today. I suppose it should be OK now.

Comment: Now it's fine :)